# Generic object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I was experimenting in some global API-parser (to check net-connection, call API & return formatted data by a single call from source) for Android using Kotlin & at some point I had to create a generic type of `object` as like the following snippet, when found the compilation error at the 1st line like `Type parameters are not allowed for objects`:

```
object RestApiParser<T> // ERROR(mark under T): Type parameters are not allowed for objects
: Callback<T> {

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>?, t: Throwable?) {
        // bla-bla-blaa codes ...
    }

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>?, response: Response<T>?) {
        // bla-bla-blaa codes ...
    }

    fun getResponse(context: Context, call: Call<T>, callback: RestApiCallback<T>) {
       // bla-bla-blaa codes ...
    }

    fun getList(context: Context, call: Call<ArrayList<T>>, callback: RestApiCallback<T>) {
       // bla-bla-blaa codes ...
    }

    // there are more codes like the above ...
}
```

I used `companion object` inside `class` delivering the same error & then had to continue reverting the `RestApiParser` to a simple class & calling that through a variable every time, which didn't satisfy our need.

Yes, singleton structure might be coded like the following companion segment using [upper-bound](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
companion object {
    private var instance: RestApiParser<*>? = null
    fun <T> getParser(): RestApiParser<T> {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = RestApiParser<T>()
        return instance as RestApiParser<T>
    }
}
```

But it would feel good to create generic object in Kotlin.

**Question:**
Is there any way to **create generic object** in Kotlin? 

If **not**, then what may **best suit** the mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An object is a singleton. A singleton is something for which only one instance exists. Type parameters allow to specify type arguments for a specific instance of a class, and as such, make sense only when there is more than one instance. Therefore, no, there is no way to create a generic object in Kotlin.

In your `RestApiParser` example, you can simply specify type parameters for each individual function and leave the `object` as non-generic. Using an `object` as a callback for REST API calls sounds like quite poor design to me (because of threading issues, among others), so I'd replace it with creating a new callback instance with proper type arguments for each call.

Comment: I've been STUPIDly blind about generic type of Singleton! ... & about design - as I mentioned I was just experimenting the design & questioned about more the syntax than the design - but thank you very much for your opinion - I'll definitely use proper callbacks for usages like REST API calls..cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Under a very strict precondition it's possible to generalize the callback implementation. You cannot use the type of the data and you will not be able to access it in any case. So you cannot make a call to *Gson* or similar utilities for example. All you should ever consider is having a pure `Object` to use.

```
object RestApiParser : Callback<Any> {
    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Any>?, t: Throwable?) = Unit

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T> asCallback(): Callback<T> = this as Callback<T>
}
```

Comment: Nice outcome - but I had to accept @yole's answer as that explains a bit more...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

just extend from the generic class calling the constructor

for example, using a `GenericClass` with a type `Employee`

```
object GenericSingleton : GenericClass<Employee>(arg1, arg2...)
```

then you can anywhere do

```
GenericSingleton.anyMethod()
```

Comment: It's not right, because compiler need  Employee.